# Unable to get actual width/height property when trying to make a square button in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make a square button with dimensions relative to the parent element's width (in Windows Phone 8.1 application)

I've found a solution like that:

```
<Button 
    MinWidth="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
    MinHeight="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        Some content
</Button>
```

Here is how I'm using it:

```
                <Button 
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
MinWidth="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
MinHeight="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    blablabla
                </Button>
```

but it works only in XAML Designer and only if it has the button element rendered (so it knows its width) and then I paste the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` rules. If I do like that I have the desired effect:

[image]

which is ruined after running the Debugger:

[image]

**Is there a way to make it work properly?**
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you know that the button will already size to it's parent without you making it do that?

Comment: @GlenThomas In my project the button fits to its text property, that's why I'm using `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: What is the parent control?

Comment: `<Grid>`. There I have some `<ColumnDefinition>`'s that define the desired width (in relative units like `2*`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make button square you can use SquareGrid control:

```
public class SquareGrid : Grid
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        availableSize = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);

        return new Size(availableSize.Width, availableSize.Width);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        finalSize = base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        Width = Height = finalSize.Width;

        return new Size(finalSize.Width, finalSize.Width);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
<SquareGrid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">blablabla</Button>
</SquareGrid>
```

Comment: Presumably you want to measure and arrange with the modified size?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT, please edit the answer if you found mistake.